# Using External Views with Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

So I have seen other posts pertaining to this question but regardless of my efforts to incorporate their suggestions, I don't seem to be able to solve the issue. So here is the code:

What am I doing wrong here and what is the best way to get the application started?

Entire Application:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults : {
    name : ""
}

});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({

el : $('body'),

tagName: 'li',

initialize : function() {
    this.render();
},

render : function(){
    var template = _.template( $("#person").html(), {} );

    this.$el.html(template);

    return this;
}

});
```

HTML w/ Template:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="person">
        <h1><%= name %></h1>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you're defining the DOM location incorrectly.

```
el : $('body'),

tagName: 'li',
```

`el` should be the jQuery selector string rather than the object

```
el : 'body'
```

but then, `this.$el` will be `$('body')` effectively, so `this.$el.html(template)` will try to put data into the `<body>` tag.

It looks like, from the `tagName: 'li'` that you want to have multiple PersonViews, so I suggest not defining the `el` property at all, then appending `this.$el` once the view has been rendered to whatever parent element you need it in.

Answer (score 0):

On further review, "entire application" suggests that you're not initialising anything.

The Javascript you have there is defining a Person class and a PersonView class. Presumably, you will want to instantiate one or more objects of the Person class and then also a PersonView for each Person, this is achieved by using `new`, as [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) mentions.

Effectively, the code you have is the setup, now you need to start it.

```
var joe = new Person;
var joeView = new PersonView({ person: joe });
```

That snippet assumes that you'll be expecting `{ person: joe }` in PersonView, which you're not, but the errors thrown should point you in a better direction.